# Не отрабатывает цикл {% for %} в Django

Tags: python, django, jinja

С помощью шаблонизатора попытался прописать вот такое вот меню:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал вот такой вот шаблон:

```
{% for m in menu %}
                {%if not forloop.last%}
            <div class="header__item headerButton"><a href="{% url m.url_name %}"> {{ m.title }} </a></div>
            {%else%}
            <div class="header__item headerButton"><a href="/">Else working</a></div>
            {%endif%}
            {% endfor %}
```

Но шаблонизатор не отрабатывает, в чем может быть проблема?

Вот сам список который хочу вывести циклом с помощью шаблонизатора в **views.py**:

```
menu = [{'title': 'Main Window', 'url_name': 'main'},
        {'title': 'Graphs', 'url_name': 'Graphs'},
        {'title': 'Import csv', 'url_name': 'Import_csv'},
        {'title': 'Import Gsheets', 'url_name': 'Import Gsheets'},
        {'title': 'login', 'url_name': 'login'},
        {'title': 'Registration', 'url_name': 'Reg'} ]
def main_window(request):

    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'title': 'Main window'})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не передаете в шаблон список, хотя и пытаетесь обратиться к нему в цикле.

```
 return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'menu': menu})
```

Comment: И правда, спасибо за помощь!